# Swift error when trying to run a reach native app in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I have created a new react-native app and when I try to run the app on an iOS emulator it doesn't seem to run and causes an error.

When I open Xcode I seem to get the following error.

[image: error]

I have never come across this error before and I have googled it and it seems that no one has come across this problem and I can't find a fix.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure to install node_modules and pod files using this command from your project's root directory.

`npm install && cd ios && pod install && cd ..`

then open your project by clicking on the `your-projectName.xcworkspace` file NOT the .xcodeproject file

Comment: done this and it was the your-projectName.xcworkspace that I opened and still had this problem